# Swift: SKLabelNode fade animation doesn't fade

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm just trying to make a SKLabelNode fade in, here's my code:

```
let welcome = SKLabelNode(text: "Welcome")
welcome.fontName = "HelveticaNeue-Light"
welcome.fontSize *= size.width/welcome.frame.width
welcome.fontColor = UIColor(white:1,alpha:0)
welcome.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
welcome.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
welcome.position = CGPoint(x:size.width/2,y:size.height/2)
addChild(welcome)

let fadein = SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 1)
let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
welcome.run(SKAction.sequence([fadein,remove]))
```

But it doesn't work, and I can't figure out why.
 The strange part is the removeFromParent part works fine, just not the fade in.
 I already tried changing the font, making the label fade out and even making a custom action that changes the alpha, all of which have failed.
 I just can't figure out what the problem is.

Any idea will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I posted this on the dev forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/192382#192382

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the `fontColor`'s `alpha` to 0, set the `SKLabelNode`'s `alpha` to 0 before running the `fadeIn` action on it.  This is because the actions are applied to the nodes themselves, not to property inside of the nodes. (E.G. In your case: `fadeIn` affects `SKLabel.alpha`, not `SKLabel.fontColor.alpha`)